# dynamically enable and disable toggle button

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js, toggle

Here is html for Toggle button

```
<div class="toggle btn btn-default" data-toggle="toggle" data-bind=" toggle:address(), css:{off:!address()}enable: IsItNeeded()">
    <div class="toggle-group">
        <label class="btn btn-primary toggle-on">On</label>
        <label class="btn btn-default active toggle-off">Off</label>
        <span class="toggle-handle btn btn-default"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my viewmodel i tried to set variable `IsItNeeded` to false but still toggle button is not getting disabled. What is way to fix this?

Comment: it would be helpful if you gave us a working fiddle

Comment: Why these parenthesis `IsItNeeded()`? See here: [The data-bind syntax](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

If `IsItNeeded` is an observable, then you need to remove the invocation `()` of that observable. You want to bind to the observable, not the value that it holds. Same with any other binding.

```
<div ... data-bind="toggle: address, enable: IsItNeeded">
  ...
</div>
```

Comment: its computed observable

Comment: i update html in question. i forgot that there is this code ", css:{off:!address()}" in data binding